# Branch Deep Link does not open application

Tags: android, branch.io

I am trying to add **Branch.io Deep Linking** to my application. Link which I generate inside the application redirects to the website instead of launching app. I noticed that when I manually open app after that it navigates to the Activity which I want to be opened via Deep Link. I added Branch.io via Fabric kit and followed step by step tutorial in Fabric about **Deep Linking Routing**. My app is not in Google Play Store yet.

Thats my configuration on website (I also checked option: `Always try to open app` and `Test` mode on the top of the dashboard). Links which I am generating should be test too, because I see `test key` in `BranchSDK:` response/request

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFkDR.jpg

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
    android:name=".app.MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
        android:value="key_live_xxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
        android:value="key_test_xxx" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="open"
                android:scheme="example" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Build.gradle

```
//...
applicationId "com.example"
//...
 compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.4.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

MainApplication

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this);
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
}
```

I can add more code snippet if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Because the app navigates to the correct activity when you manually launch it after clicking a link, this means that *most* of your configuration is correct. The only piece that appears to be missing is the code that triggers your app to actually launch.

On Android, Branch uses your URI scheme for this. That is this section of code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="open"
        android:scheme="example" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

You need to replace the `example` value in the `android:scheme="example"` piece of this with some other, custom string. Then make sure you have that same string (plus `://`) in the [Link Settings](https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link) section of the Branch dashboard.

That should be enough to get you up and running here. You may also want to check out our [full developer documentation](https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link). The Fabric guides are a great way to get started, but they only cover a small fraction of the functionality available through Branch!

Comment: I changed `https` in generated link to `http` and it started working.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know what to write in the `scheme` field. I suggest you to remove the `example` word in the documentation and put a clearer string like `http://your.example.scheme/for.links`, because people gets confused and does not know what to write there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted solution does not work for you then try checking the `Always try to open app` option at the top of https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings.